# Angular2 typing pattern directive

Tags: angular, typescript

I am looking for a directive I could add to an input (so using ngModel) which would prevent typing or pasting any string which doesn't match a given pattern.

I did manage to write by updating the model in a `keypress`, but I am not sure how to deal with the copy and paste thing.

Here is what I've written so far :

```
import { Directive, Input, HostListener, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core"


@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][typingPattern]'
})

export class TypingPatternDirective  {

  @Input() typingPattern: string
  @Input() ngModel
  @Output() ngModelChange = new EventEmitter()
  private oldValue: any

  /* On key down, we record the old value */
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown($event) {
    this.oldValue = $event.target.value
    if($event.keyCode === 32) { // Prevent space key
        $event.preventDefault()
    }
  }

  /* On changing value, we check if the max length is reached. If not, we do nothing, otherwise we put the old value */
  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event'])
  onKeypress($event) {
    if ( !$event.target.value.match( new RegExp(this.typingPattern))) {
      $event.target.value = this.oldValue.trim()
      this.ngModelChange.emit($event.target.value)
    }
  }

}
```

As I mentionned this doesn't deal with copy and paste. I want to always use this directive on an `input` element (thus I want to be sure it does update the InputComponent error states as well which is not the case now).

Comment: `@HostListener('onpaste', ['$event']) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

Have a try at using [`npm install angular2-text-mask`](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2), I think it suits your needs.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15505912)

Comment: Take a look at this part of the documentation then: https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/blob/master/componentDocumentation.md#mask-function